# scipy.optimize.curve_fit failing to fit curve

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve

I am trying to fit some data using the following code:

```
xdata = [0.03447378,  0.06894757,  0.10342136,  0.13789514,  0.17236893,
    0.20684271,  0.24131649,  0.27579028,  0.31026407,  0.34473785,
    0.37921163,  0.41368542,  0.44815921,  0.48263299]

ydata = [ 2.5844 ,  2.87449,  3.01929,  3.10584,  3.18305,  3.24166,
    3.28897,  3.32979,  3.35957,  3.39193,  3.41662,  3.43956,
    3.45644,  3.47135]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*x - c*np.exp(-d*x)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ko', label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The curve is not being fitted:

[Data fit with straight line - should be curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfWKN.png)

What should I be doing to correctly fit the data?

Comment: Which values of `popt` and `pcov` are returned by `curve_fit()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the optimizer is getting stuck in a local minimum, or perhaps just a very flat area of the objective function.  A better fit can be found by tweaking the initial guess of the parameters that is used by `curve_fit`.  For example, I get a reasonable-looking fit with `p0=[1, 1, 1, 2.0]` (the default is [1, 1, 1, 1]):

[image: plot]

Here's the modified version of your script that I used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*x - c*np.exp(-d*x)


xdata = np.array([0.03447378,  0.06894757,  0.10342136,  0.13789514,  0.17236893,
    0.20684271,  0.24131649,  0.27579028,  0.31026407,  0.34473785,
    0.37921163,  0.41368542,  0.44815921,  0.48263299])

ydata = np.array([ 2.5844 ,  2.87449,  3.01929,  3.10584,  3.18305,  3.24166,
    3.28897,  3.32979,  3.35957,  3.39193,  3.41662,  3.43956,
    3.45644,  3.47135])

p0 = [1, 1, 1, 2.0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=p0)
print(popt)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ko', label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

The printed output is:

```
[  3.13903988   0.71827903   0.97047248  15.40936232]
```

Comment: Had similar problems as op. Most of the times the p0 values where wrong. It might be added that for each scalar value there are two directions possible ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to be more specific with the issue you're having.

Two things I noticed that will prevent your code from working as it is:

- line 15 (the `curve_fit()` call), there is an additional right paranthesis at the end of the line
- `xdata` is a python list, so this won't work once you try to multiply it with a parameter in `func`, i.e. turn it into a numpy array with 
  `xdata = np.array(xdata)`

If you fix these two issues, the fit should work.

Edit: Warren is of course right - fixing the above issues still will get you started in a wrong minimum.